# How does the "Cricket" badge affect Hooktail's stats?

Tags: paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door

In *Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door*, when you wear the "Cricket" badge (Attack FX R badge), the boss Hooktail becomes easier to fight. How does it make the fight easier? From what I've been able to find online, it lowers Hooktail's stats, but they don't say by how much.

How does the the "Cricket" badge affect Hooktails stats/behavior? What are the stats/behavior with and without the badge equipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Attack_FX_R):

> During the battle against Hooktail, if Mario attacks with the badge equipped, Hooktail exclaims her distaste for the badge, and **her attack and defense are both lowered by one** (to a minimum of one and zero, respectively) **every time Mario attacks and the sound effect plays**.

Emphasis mine.

Since Hooktail starts with **5 attack** and **1 defense**, you need **4** attacks to maximize your diminution.

Comment: From the same site I found the info that her initial attack is 5 and her initial defense is 1. Can you add this information to your answer please so it is more complete?